# Как проверить был ли куплен определенный товар

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как проверить был ли куплен определенный товар, по id например

Пример:

Человек оформил заказ с 2 позициями, у одной id 1 у второй id 2. Нужно проверять, если человек купил товар с id 2, то выводить true_two, если купил с id 5то выводить true_five

В данном случае должно вывести true_two

Comment: "Купил" и "оформил" разные вещи. Где/как/когда "выводить" - не ясно. Но похоже ты опять решаешь проблему молотка.

Comment: Да, немного не так написал, купил. А выводить без разницы, это я для примера написал. Просто нужно как-то узнавать человек купил этот товар или нет

Comment: Это и так ясно по оплате.

Comment: Мне нужно условие, что если человек купил определённый товар, то что-то делать, поэтому и нужно узнавать купил человек этот товар или нет, а не по оплате смотреть

Comment: "Купил" = "Оплатил". Это ты получаешь от эквайринга. ВП тут не причём.

Comment: Нужно более конкретно описать задачу (условия и вводные). Где и когда ты хочешь сообщить человеку (на какой странице) и (на каком этапе)? По возможности указать цель этого мероприятия, в этом случае бывалые (возможно) смогут предложить более верное решение. **Из вопроса не понятно, ты хочешь проверить на этапе посещения карточки, в корзине или в процессе оформления заказа?** Это важно, поскольку в этих 3 разных вариантах, будут задействованы разные хуки и шаблоны.